# Check for parameter in url twig

Tags: twig, canonical-link

I've got

> 132&attribute%5B23%5D%5B%5D=Truffe+de+bourgogne&ajax_digitalElephantFilter=1

ending in url, and I need to check my url for some of this parameter and if yes rewrite canonical for this page, how can i do it.

Comment: With Twig being a template engine, there's no function or filter to access request vars. You either need to provide this via the php code that calls to render, or write a twig extension. I'd suggest the former.

Comment: can i make it via php and connect it with my theme(that using twig) - im using opencart and my theme is twig oriented?

Comment: Maybe you have an example how i can do it ,  m i right that i need to do it via controller ? If you can write an example  it will helps , thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any experience with opencart, but yes, you should handle this kind of logic inside the controller and then pass the final value (probably as `['canonical' => $someVar, /*other view values*/]` to the view. Though there might already be a predefined way to get a canonical url for a given product within opencart. Maybe even a twig extension. So first, I'd advice you to check the docs.

Comment: im open category.php and find this lines of code into my catalog/controller/product folder - 
if ($page == 1) {
       $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id']), 'canonical');
   } else {
    $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'] . '&page='. $page), 'canonical');
   } , what i should add to check url for my  request vars